# Jquery, split select value to two strings and assign to two inputs using arrays

Tags: jquery, html

I need to split the value of my html select option and pass the split results into two separate input fields. I tried to code this before but ended up with a not so DRY result.

> Could someone help me understand how to pass an array's value to each
> element in another array? *This was even confusing to write. :(*

This is what I have so far;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#media-size').change(function() {
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
    var arr = selectValue.split("x");
    var valOne = arr[0];
    var valTwo = arr[1];

      $('.media-value').each(function() {
        $(this).val(arr);
    });
  });
});
```

Here's a link to the fiddle I've been working on; [Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Beaniie/2txomfhr/31/)

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Regards, -B.

P.s.

To clarify, before this question is marked as a duplicate. I'm looking for a Jquery answer, not a java answer which is all I seem to be able to find on the subject.

Comment: Are there **only** 2 `.media-value` inputs? Or more?

Comment: @M12 Bennett There are only two.

Comment: I would actually recommend using data elements for this on each option, so you don't have to do any split logic.

Comment: I understand that's a route I could have taken, but I'm trying to force myself to learn a little more complex Jquery coding. Stupidly I thought this would be a great place to start... -.- * (face palm)

Comment: The main reason I suggest this is because it's a typical pattern in coding that if you find yourself taking data and breaking it down into sub-parts to use, it becomes a code smell to determine if you should change your data model so you do not have to do that logic every time.  If the majority of the time you need the smaller parts, you should provide the smaller parts in the data model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you where really close. You just need to get the `index` of the iteration to get the specific arra value.

I recomend you follow the jQuery documentation for [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Hope this help :>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#media-size').change(function() {
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
    var arr = selectValue.split("x");

    $('.media-value').each(function(index) {
      $(this).val(arr[index]);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select" id="media-size">
  <option value="00x00" selected>Finish Size...</option>
  <option value="594x841">A1</option>
  <option value="420x594">A2</option>
  <option value="297x420">A3</option>
  <option value="210x297">A4</option>
  <option value="148x210">A5</option>
  <option value="105x148">A6</option>
  <option value="74x105">A7</option>
  <option value="85x55">UK Business Card</option>
  <option value="85x54">UK Plastic Card</option>
  <option value="00x00">Custom Size</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control media-value" placeholder="00" aria-label="Finish size in millimetres" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
<span>x</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control media-value" placeholder="00" aria-label="Finish size in millimetres" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
```

Comment: Wonderful, Thanks for the assist. I basically get the idea, but don't fully understand the docs. I think I'll need to read up a little more before I fully grasp it.

Comment: Jajajaja its practice mostly. Code On!

Answer (score 1):

Offering an alternative to the split logic.

```js
/*
   This logic suggests using data attributes on your options, such as...
   <option data-width="640" data-height="480">640x480</option>
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $mediaSize = $('#media-size');
  var $mediaValues = $('.media-value');

  $mediaSize.change(function() {
    var $selectedOption = $mediaSize.find('option:selected');
    
    //optionally you could give each media value a class to
    //specify width or height, and filter on that, rather
    //than using eq()
    $mediaValues.eq(0).val($selectedOption.data('width'));
    $mediaValues.eq(1).val($selectedOption.data('height'));
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for covering all bases. This just felt a bit bulky to me though, and the cleaner logic felt more appealing. (Even if it is a pain to understand.)

Comment: Please keep in mind that one objective of coding is to make things readable.  Readability leads to maintainability, which is paramount for the majority of programmers.  @Beaniie